# Service - Live Agent

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Somedoy knows how Live Agent manage the information the information getted from customer??

I can see some problems based on storage this information. How can use Live Agen without this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about chat between customer and agent? It is stored as Transcript record on each chat initiated.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about chat. My doubt is about different ways for store the transcript records

Comment: What is the issue with transcript? and What do you want to achieve? Whenever a transcript record is created it is automatically related to the case more like a related records which can be multiple.

Comment: I want to know, how can we configure Live Agent for save Transcript. It´s mandatory save all??? The data-storega go up very quickly

Comment: To save transcripts, we have `findOrCreate.saveToTranscript`. The implementation depends on the API you are using [pre-chat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_prechat_API_saveToTranscript.htm) or [deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_API_saveToTranscript.htm). Yes, It save all. I do not remember anything configurable as such.